# "npm install --save" cmd says cannot find buffer-shims after I "rm -rf node_modules && npm install"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I run cmd `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`, it seems nothing interesting happens. But after that, when I run `npm uninstall react-native-router-flux`, it starts to say it cannot find module buffer-shims

I found that from now on whenever I `npm install --save something` or "`npm uninstall --save something`:
it gives this error:

```
node-gyp@3.6.0 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /home/raymond/IdeaProjects/puppysky/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:474
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'buffer-shims'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raymond/IdeaProjects/puppysky/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:33:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
```

After seeing the error, I try to `npm install --save buffer-shims`, but it says:

```
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.0 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /home/raymond/IdeaProjects/puppysky/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:474
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'console-control-strings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raymond/IdeaProjects/puppysky/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/gauge/plumbing.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
```

After seeing this, I try to `npm install --save console-control-strings`, which of course goes back to the first problem again (cannot find buffer-shims)

I have tried to `npm install -g buffer-shims` and `npm link buffer-shims`
but it does not solve the problem.

npm version: v5.0.1,   node version: v7.0.0

Comment: What happens if you just run `npm i` (`npm install`)

Comment: @TimeDead npm i works but it does not install buffer-shims for me

Comment: So it looks like `npm i` works but whenever you run `npm` with options in the command it throw all of these errors?

EDIT (Since I hit enter by accident): you may want to try reinstalling your node/npm sounds like something may have gotten corrputed

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem that happens with node-sass after migrating to npm 5.

These commands made it work for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Source: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1991